# PyInstaller error with python script that uses OpenCV and VPython (DOS Header magic not found)

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, pyinstaller, vpython

I am trying to generate exe file from a script that uses openCV and Vpython however I am having problems with it. I tried using pyinstaller with a simple print script it worked fine. when I try it with openCV only script it did not work and the same with Vpython only script, and both. the error I am getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_
build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'
))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line
161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
535, in assemble
    redirects=self.binding_redirects))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 227
, in Dependencies
    for lib, npth in selectImports(pth, xtrapath):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 510
, in selectImports
    npth = getfullnameof(lib, xtrapath)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 82,
 in getfullnameof
    if os.path.exists(npth) and matchDLLArch(npth):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 194
, in matchDLLArch
    pe = pefile.PE(filename, fast_load=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\pefile.py", line 1720, in
__init__
    self.__parse__(name, data, fast_load)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\pefile.py", line 1799, in
__parse__
    raise PEFormatError('DOS Header magic not found.')
PyInstaller.lib.pefile.PEFormatError: 'DOS Header magic not found.'
```

I have:

```
PyInstaller: 3.2.1
Python: 2.7.13 x64
Platform: Windows-8.1 x64
```

what to do?

Answer (score 1):

A better place to pose VPython questions is in the VPython forum at

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users

There you might find VPython users who have experience with PyInstaller (I don't).

Comment: Thank you, I did work around it by installing a virtual machine and install everything on it 32bit then try over there, it worked fine. I kept this just in case someone might have an answer could help in the future.